# AngularJS form with multiple http requests

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple select/drop-downs in my html form. Each one depends on the next. For example

in my HTML form I have multiple selects:

```
<td><select ng-model="ASelect" ng-options="a for a in A"></select></td>
<td><select ng-model="BSelect" ng-options="b for b in B"></select></td>
<td><select ng-model="CSelect" ng-options="c for c in C"></select></td>
```

in my controller I have:

```
$http.get('/getA').
    success(function(data) {
            $scope.A = data;
        });

$http.get('/getB?A=' + $scope.ASelect).
    success(function(data) {
            $scope.B = data;
        });

$http.get('/getC?A=' + $scope.ASelect + '&B=' + $ scope.BSelect).
    success(function(data) {
            $scope.B = data;
        });
```

I'm not sure how to do it, I need to have A selected first before B can get populated with data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$watch` to call your function whenever the value it needs changed, and make sure it has a value so it doesn't fire when they select nothing or on page load sometimes:

In your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('ASelect', function(aSelect) {
     if (typeof aSelect != "undefined" && aSelect.length ) {
         $http.get('/getB?A=' + $scope.ASelect).success(function(data) {
             $scope.B = data;
         });
     }
});

$scope.$watch('BSelect', function(bSelect) {
     if (typeof bSelect != "undefined" && bSelect.length ) {
         $http.get('/getC?B=' + $scope.ASelect).success(function(data) {
             $scope.C = data;
         });
     }
});
```

The other option is `ng-change`:

```
<select ng-model="ASelect" ng-options="a for a in A" ng-change="getB()">

$scope.getB = function() {
     $http.get('/getB?A=' + $scope.ASelect).success(function(data) {
         $scope.B = data;
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! which one would you prefer to use? I will apply it now and see if it works

Comment: I applied the second method and it works, thank you!